# Javascript event removing

Tags: javascript, events

Another Javascript , probobly for you minor problem , but i just can not understand how to fix it , googled all night for it , problem is simple ... i have table and inside td's i got buttons and i assigned `onclick` event on all of them , so when i click a button i do a function and at the end of function i want to change that event to go for another function
here is my code ...

```
var $UserRow = $(Final).closest('tr').clone();

$('td button', $UserRow).each(function () {

   this.removeEventListener('click', GetInfo, false);
   this.addEventListener('click', GetBetslip, false);
});

$UserRow.appendTo('#UserTicket');
```

So `$UserRow` is a row that i want to copy to another table and that part is working fine , but before i copy it i want to remove all button events ... i have tried with everything from

```
this.removeEventListener('click',GetInfo,false);
this.detachEvent('Click', GetInfo);
this.onclick = GetBetslip;
this.onclick = function () { GetBetslip()};
```

i just do not know what to try anymore ... can you just help me out ... all i want is to change event for every button inside that tr.

Comment: If you are using jQuery I suggest you add and remove events using `.on` and `.off` respectively.

Comment: And change the button to type="button" instead of submit if you are not submitting a form using the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using jQuery, if that is the case you are looking for [this function. `$().off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

According to the comments you might do better with this:

```
$(this).attr('onclick', false);
```

Comment: But i have attached event over HTML
`<button class="LeftSideTeams" type="submit" name="<?php echo $rez?>" id="1" onclick="GetInfo(this.name,this.id)">`

Comment: @SidharthMudgal why does it matter how he bound it? He can remove it with JQuery. He's obviously using the library. JQuery is just built on top of JavaScript, so he's using JS regardless.

Comment: "The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()". Your second method does work though...

Comment: Hrm...I didn't know that. That's strange to me, but who am I to question the JQuery folks. =)

Answer (score 2):

If using jQuery, its preferable to bind AND unbind events using jQuery. You can use this method ONLY if you bind your handlers using jQuery:

Do this instead:

```
$('td button', $UserRow).each(function () {

   $(this).off('click', GetInfo);
   $(this).on('click', GetBetslip);
});
```

Comment: I did as you said but with use of firebug i see copied row goes into both functions `GetInfo` and `GetBetslip`